# ZIndex Windows Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-video, z-index

I have a problem with the z-index of a video tag in windows mobile, my search box

```
<div portal:substituteby='common/search::search'></div>
```

should be over the video

```
                        <a th:if="${hrefCinemagraph}!='#'" th:href="${hrefCinemagraph}" th:target="${targetCinemagraph}" class="center">
                            <div>
                                <div class="navigation"></div>
                                <img the:src="@{${imageCinemagraph}}" alt="Ofertas de viajes" title="Ofertas de viajes"/>
                            </div>
                        </a>
```

but in windows mobile its impossible to make it look like that if I use the z-index property, the video is always on the top.

Both elements (div and a href) have absolute position in their css.

I have tried to set the properties with jquery after the page is loaded, but it doesn't work either:

```
    setTimeout(
              function() 
              {
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#video').css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
                        $('#video').css("z-index",1);
                        $('#video').css("position","absolute");
                        $('#buscador').css("position","absolute");
                        $('#buscador').css("z-index",1000000);
                        alert("video z index is " + $('#video').zIndex());
                        alert("buscador z index is " + $('#buscador').zIndex());
                    });
              }, 5000);
```

My code:

```
                <div class="gallery">
                    <section>
                        <div portal:substituteby='common/search::search'></div>
                        <a th:if="${hrefCinemagraph}!='#'" th:href="${hrefCinemagraph}" th:target="${targetCinemagraph}" class="center">
                            <div>
                                <div class="navigation"></div>
                                <img the:src="@{${imageCinemagraph}}" alt="Ofertas de viajes" title="Ofertas de viajes"/>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div th:if="${hrefCinemagraph}=='#'" class="center">
                            <div class="navigation"></div>
                            <img the:src="@{${imageCinemagraph}}" alt="Ofertas de viajes" title="Ofertas de viajes" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="right"></div>
                    </section>
                </div>
```

I have spent a whole day trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this many time we finally decided to hide the video tag in mobile devices to prevent the problem with z-index in a video tag and windows phone.